# memcpy seems to be stuck

Tags: c, memcpy

I am trying to use a memcpy for a size of 200K, and it stucks!!!

Both destb and source are allocated.

What could be the reason for this issue?

Comment: Need more information. What do you mean it's "stuck"? What message are you getting? Provide sample code showing the problem -- should be the smallest valid program that exhibits the behavior.

Comment: What compiler, what hardware, what types for parameters. It can be buffer overflows, integer range overflow, whatever.

Comment: you should also provide the code, you may have make a mistake.

Comment: post your code for better understanding!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using some tool that traces memory accesses. Valgrind is my favourite one.

If you're not able to do so, at least try printing out the source and dest pointer values to the console, and make sure they are in fact allocated, non-overlapping and of the right size.